# Want a list of prime numbers returned from my function but only getting the first value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I have the following function:

```
def prime(number):
    for num in range(1,number):
        if num > 1:
            for i in range (2, num):
                if (num%i == 0):
                    return("not a prime")
            else:
                return(num)

print(prime(9))
```

> Output: 2

Please explain where I am doing a mistake or how can I get a list of all prime numbers in any input range ex:-9 or 100 or 300.

Comment: keep in mind that when you reach a `return` statement, the function terminates.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf is there any method to get my list as output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you reach the `return` statement, the function execution terminates, so you will only get the first prime. Consider creating a list in which you will append your prime numbers as follows:

```py
def prime(number):
    primes = []
    for num in range(1, number + 1):
        if num > 1:
            for i in range (2, num):
                if (num % i == 0):
                    break
            else:
                primes.append(num)
    return primes
```

This will give you the prime numbers from 2 up to `number`. I hope this helps you.

As suggested by @jpp, you can also use `yield` as follows:

```py
def prime(number):
    for num in range(1,number):
        if num > 1:
            for i in range (2, num):
                if (num%i == 0):
                    break
            else:
                yield num

for num in prime(20):
    print(num)
```

Comment: @SameerKumarPandey, just keep in mind that this is not an efficient algorithm.

Comment: @SameerKumarPandey, you're welcome. I hope you can validate/upvote my answer too.

Comment: Why is it not an efficient algorithm..please explains? Please give the better code?

Comment: Or just replace `return` in the original code with `yield`, then use `next` on the generator.

Comment: It is not efficient because you are trying to find a number that divides your current `num` from 2 up to `num - 1`. However, you can go up to `int(number ** 0.5)`. There are other ways to generate prime numbers you can read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: @jpp Could you please show how?

Comment: @SameerKumarPandey, I just updated my answer. Adding the way you could use `yield` and then using a for loop which underneath the hood calls `next` every time it is generating a number.